# How to make the navigation bar transparent

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

How can I make the navigation bar transparent on Android 4.4.X and above?

I have searched in the documentation, but found nothing about this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have taken this from the change log for [Android KitKat (4.4)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html):

> **Translucent system bars**
>
> You can now make the system bars partially translucent with new themes, [`Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor) and [`Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor). By enabling translucent system bars, your layout will fill the area behind the system bars, so you must also enable [`fitsSystemWindows`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fitsSystemWindows) for the portion of your layout that should not be covered by the system bars.
>
> If you're creating a custom theme, set one of these themes as the parent theme or include the [`windowTranslucentNavigation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentNavigation) and [`windowTranslucentStatus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentStatus) style properties in your theme.

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: Actually if you use fitSystemWindows to true in the theme, you may affect to other views like toasts and dialogs, see this answer https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63653

Comment: What is written above is correct then, according to the answer. 
"fitsSystemWindows for the **portion** of your layout that should not be covered by the system bars." and in the answer: "You should only specify fitsSystemWindows on **views within your layouts** or in styles that you explicitly apply to views within your layouts, not on themes."

Comment: Nexus 10 doesn't support it in 4.4.4. Immersive mode has its usual transparency but TRANS_STATUS and TRANS_NAV are ignored when showing "real" status and nav

Answer (score 3):

I used your trevor-e's answer, by creating a custom theme in my styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.HomeScreen" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor">
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
             <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
        </style>
```

and then you can set the theme from the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="MyActivity" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.HomeScreen" >
     </activity>
```