# Transparent Status Bar Android 4.3

Tags: java, android, eclipse, transparency, statusbar

In the 'new' Android Version 4.3 there is a new feature. The status Bar on the top of the screen is transparent in the launcher (I'm using Samsung TouchWiz on Galaxy S3) and in some other Apps too I think (looks a little bit like the iOS 7 style). 
Can you tell me how I can make the Status Bar transparent (or colored) in my own App (Eclipse, Java)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor 

Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor
```

Based on the best answer here: [How to make the navigation bar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732972/how-to-make-the-navigation-bar-transparent)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the transparency but as of API 10 you can set a background drawable for the actionBar. (and thus a color)
In the following codesnippet I get a color based on an attribute (depending on the theme chosen)

```
TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{R.attr.background_activity_color});
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(a.getDrawable(0));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I speak about the Status-Bar, not the ActionBar. Your can see it on this picture: http://fs01.androidpit.info/userfiles/2732026/image/android-kitkat-translucent-status-bar.jpg

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry then. :) I recommend you to edit your last sentence as you've used "action bar" there.