# How to make the notification background transparent?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I use a RemoteView to display some content in the notification area, but I want it's background to be transparent, just like the app Notification Weather.

I try to set the background color to transparent and alpha to 0, but no use...

[image: Notify]

How can I do the same effect?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this link -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732972/how-to-make-the-navigation-bar-transparent

Comment: Whats your minSDKversion ?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 16, I try the reference answer, but some error say not found "Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor"

Comment: Try increasing the minSDKVersion but be aware that your app would be supported only on higher end OS versions.

Comment: May I know the version of Android used in the mobile used to take the above screen shot ?

Comment: But I can see the transparent effect of Notification Weather in my mobile phone, its android version is 4.1.2. I think minSDKversion 16 is enough.

Comment: Could you please tell me the error that gets thrown in your manifest file while trying to add the theme ?

Comment: I set the <style> attribute parent to "android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor" and I get the Error "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor'"

Comment: Try setting your target SDK version to 19.