# Navigation Drawer & Toolbar with tabs

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, material-design

Well guys, my error is simple.

I'm implementing an Custom Toolbar like action bar on and Android Application and implementing an Navigation drawer.

The issue is that i'm using material design theme, so the navigation drawer start on the top of the screen behind the status bar, and take all the screen height, but if i do that, all the buttons and tabs on the main activity, get unclicable, cause the elevation of the navigation drawer is 7dp and the action bar is 4. How can i solve that? And another question, how to make the status bar a little bit transparent and the make the background getting dark when show the navigation drawer?

I want to do this effect and let my tabs clickable:

[image]

**Main.java**

```
    package com.saturdaynight;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Home","Events"};
    int Numboftabs =2;

    String TITLES[] = {"Home", "Events", "Mail", "Shop"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

    String NAME = "Akash Bangad";
    String EMAIL = "akash.bangad@android4devs.com";
    int PROFILE = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES, ICONS, NAME, EMAIL, PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager

        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }


        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**activity_main**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>


<com.saturdaynight.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:elevation="7sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make the status bar a little bit transparent and the make the
>   background getting dark when show the navigation drawer?

**Translucent system bars**

> You can now make the system bars partially translucent with new
>   themes, [**Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor) and
>   [**Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor). B*y enabling
>   translucent system bars*, your layout will fill the area behind the
>   system bars, so you must also enable fitsSystemWindows for the portion
>   of your layout that should not be covered by the system bars.

If you're creating a custom theme, set one of these themes as the parent theme or include the `windowTranslucentNavigation` and `windowTranslucentStatus` style properties in your theme.

Also, see the best answer in here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19733218/4945820

By the way, when the drawer is showing, i think the background will be showing with dark color.Also, if you using with this tutorial*(from - android4devs)*, it can show to you the dark color after the drawer is showing.

- Using : `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This material design navigation drawer template http://androidshenanigans.blogspot.com/2015/03/material-design-template.html worked perfectly