# Cannot make status bar translucent

Tags: java, android, statusbar, translucency, android-statusbar

***EDIT:*** The more relevant question is posted here: [MaterialDrawer library turns a translucent status bar into a opaque one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818363/materialdrawer-library-turns-a-translucent-status-bar-into-a-opaque-one)

---

I know it can be done in API19+. Also I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167755/transparent-status-bar-system-ui-on-4-4-kit-kat) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732972/how-to-make-the-navigation-bar-transparent) and it seems that it can be done very easily. However I can't get it done. Here is my theme in `values-v19` folder:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

I have also changed the appcompat theme to `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor` (and of course using `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`); Nothing changed.

This is the screen shot from genymotion emulator api-22 (solid status bar; same result on real device):

[image]

And now here's the weird thing: In the preview window of the layout, when you select api-23 (on both appcompat and holo themes), I get this result (translucent):

[image]

and the preview for api-19 (also api-21 and 22) is this:

[image]

It's very confusing and I don't know what have I done wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT:***

If I add:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
```

the solid status bar changes color:

[image]

The other weird thing is the navigation drawer goes beyond the damn bar:

[image]

Comment: that should work. have a look here if you missed anything -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732972/how-to-make-the-navigation-bar-transparent

Comment: Have you tried this on a physical device?

Comment: @Tasos Actually there's nothing much to miss. I've read it thousand times.

Comment: @V_J Yeah, I have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Try removing, <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>. Let me know the result.

Comment: there's a tutorial here -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGFUGCjAGw4  -- at least you see it working

Comment: looking at that tutorial, 3:54 you need to create custom style for version 19 kitcat so it picks it up

Comment: @V_J nope didn't help

Comment: @Tasos Thanks. Nothing new though.

Comment: I've added an edit which makes it a little more confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the source of the problem. I was using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library for adding a drawer to my activity. When I removed it, everything worked perfectly. I will post another question to issue this problem and will add the link to that in an edit.

Comment: i assume you have used my drawer a bit wrong. as the translucent statusbar is automatically handled by the drawer. you can even look at the sample application. i would really love to investigate in this a bit more as your answer states the library was the issue

Comment: Hi @mikepenz. Please see the question which I have posted right now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818363/materialdrawer-library-turns-a-translucent-status-bar-into-a-opaque-one

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, added in styles-v21.xml:

```
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

and in activity_main.xml under `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`:

```
    android:android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

styles-v21.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <include
            android:id="@id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide more of an explanation with your code? It might help the OP or future users more.