# MaterialDrawer library turns a translucent status bar into a opaque one

Tags: android, translucency, android-statusbar, materialdrawer

I am using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library for adding a drawer to my activities. The activities must have translucent status bar. Like the picture below:

[image]

This is the top part of my activity, when the library has not added to it yet.

When I add a drawer using the library:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DrawerMenu.addTo(this);
    }

}
```

And the `DrawerMenu` helper class:

```
public class DrawerMenu {
    public static void addTo(final Activity activity) {
        AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(activity)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.drawer_header)
            .addProfiles(
                    new ProfileDrawerItem()
                            .withName("Ashkan")
                            .withEmail("ashkan@sarlak.com")
                            .withIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.profile_pic))
            )
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();

        new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(activity)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
            .addDrawerItems(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Login"))
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int i, IDrawerItem iDrawerItem) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Login!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .build();
    }
}
```

I will get this result:

[image]

The status bar is obviously non translucent and activity content is not below it.

However when I open the drawer, it goes beneath the status bar:

[image]

Also this is the theme that I'm applying to the activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
</style>
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you have posted looks like your app should be displayed in fullscreen mode.

So with the screenshots you posted you use the basic configuration of the **MaterialDrawer**.
In most cases people who use the drawer want their content (including the **Toolbar**) to be displayed below the **StatusBar** but the **drawer** behind the **StatusBar**.  So what basically happens here is that the logic of the **MaterialDrawer** will set your app into the translucent **StatusBar** mode so the content will move behind it. Additionally it will add the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` which will then add the padding to the top so the content will be below the **StatusBar**.

In your case you want your content also to go behind the **StatusBar** so you want to also move your content behind the **StatusBar**.

This can be implemented by adding the `withFullscreen(true)` flag to the `Builder` of the **MaterialDrawer**

This is how it's done programmatically

```
//Create the drawer
result = new DrawerBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withFullscreen(true)
    .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
    .build();
```

This will also make your **NavigationBar** translucent.

There is an open issue about this topic which will probably also improve the behavior here. 
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/698

So implementing an additional flag to don't include the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/698#issuecomment-143674729

Ok as an addition. If you want just the **StatusBar** to be translucent. then you have to do following.
Use one of the `TranslucentStatus` themes (or a child of it) for this activity

```
@style/MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.TranslucentStatus
```

And then build the drawer as shown here:

```
//Create the drawer
result = new DrawerBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withFullscreen(true)
    .withTranslucentNavigationBarProgrammatically(false)
//note that the translucentNavigationBarProgrammatically comes AFTER the withFullscreen method
```

This will result in an transparent **StatusBar** but with a black **NavigationBar**

Comment: Yes it is displaying in full screen as the theme I've posted suggesting. I guess it would be helpful if you could state that info about full-screen activities in the README as full-screen mode is common in designs right now. Thanks btw , it solved the problem. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @AshkanSarlak yeah i always think that people check out the sample application and run it, as it is also on google play. Just to inform you. i've extended the answer on how to get only translucent StatusBar and normal NavigationBar

Comment: Oh I forgot to say that. Your original answer did NOT make the NavigarionBar translucent. I guess it's because of the theme and <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item> attribute.

Comment: @AshkanSarlak yeah could be. I just thought i add the info so others who read this will have an easier time fixing their problem